# Instancing Multiple Objects Lowers Framerate of WEBGL Application

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, 3d, three.js, webgl

I am developing a THREE.JS WebGL application where I need to render multiple objects with the same geometry and I've stumbled upon a bottleneck. It seems that my instancing of objects has some issue, that I can't really understand/realize, maybe someone can help me with that. For context, I have a PointCloud with normals, that gives me information about where to position my instanced objects, and also the orientation of the object through the normal quaternion. Then, I loop through this array, and place each instanced object accordingly. After looking at various posts about instancing, merging, etc, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I attach the code snippet of the method in question :

bitbucket.org/snippets/electricganesha/Mdddz

After reviewing it multiple times, I'm really wondering what is wrong here, and why does this particular method slow down my application from 60fps to 20fps.

Comment: how many points/objects are you instancing?

Comment: around 300 objects with the following geometry each : 1254 points, 4884 vertices, 1232 primitives

Comment: just to clarify, by "instancing", do you mean this? https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/ANGLE_instanced_arrays/

Comment: no, by instancing I mean loading the object and texture once, and replicating it in a cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be overcompensating with the optimization.

In your loop where you merge all these geometries try to add something like this

```
var maxVerts = 1 << 16;

//if merging a new object causes the vert number to go over 2^16 push the merged geometry somewhere, and make a new one for the next batch
if( singleGeometry.vertices.length + newObject.geometry.vertices.length > maxVerts ){
  scene.add(singleGeometry);
  singleGeometry = new Geometry();
}

singleGeometry.merge(newObject.geometry, newObject.matrix);
```

Comment: i will try this approach, but should the rendering of 300 objects, even without merging geometry, be so heavy?

Comment: 300 it shouldnt, 3000 should even be fine depending on what is going on exactly, but from what i saw you're not doing that, you're sticking everything into one mesh and three.js does not seem to like that, at least didnt until very recently

Comment: OK, so I tried your approach, it doesn't improve, same performance as before. I also tried not merging the geometries and adding object by object, without merging, and it worsens my performance in 5fps.

I'm completely puzzled by this.

Comment: i guess its really hard to help here without seeing more of the code, and an actual live demo

Comment: ultimately, I figured out that the issue was with my machine/graphics card, and having a lot of heavy geometry being processed, despite the optimizations. I ended up simplifying the geometry and using normal maps to simulate the details, and this improved a LOT on the performance. Thank you all for your replies!

Comment: how big was your mesh?

Comment: around 300 objects with the following geometry each : 1254 points, 4884 vertices, 1232 primitives